# Slideshow with visible nax/previous slide

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slideshow

I am looking for a jQuery slideshow-plugin (or a Wordpress-plugin) for slideshows like this one: http://www.louisiana.dk/ where the previous and next slide is visible but faded out.

I have been searching but could not find something that was responsive and able to display the center slide in the middle for all devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ should do what you need. You'll need to just check out the options available in the demos. It's very flexible. You will need an understanding of jQuery and css though.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Surely a question that is looking for link to a plugin can be answered with a link to appropriate plugin?